Type error for Rc<RefCell<T>> for .borrow() function?
I thought .borrow() on RefCell just returned Ref?
pub struct NodeData {
    name: String,
    // ... other fields
}

pub struct Node {
    parent: Option<Rc<RefCell>>,
    data: Vec<NodeData>,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn get_data(&self, name: &String) -> Option<&NodeData> {
        match self.data.iter().position(|data| data.name == *name) {
            None => if let Some(parent) = &self.parent {
                let parent = parent.borrow(); // <-- Error here
                parent.get_data(name)
            } else {
                None
            },
            Some(index) => self.data.get(index)
        }
    }
}

And the error is this:
error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `&Borrowed`
  --> src\global.rs:60:21
   |
60 |                 let parent = parent.borrow();
   |                     ^^^^^^
61 |                 parent.get_data(name)
   |                        ---------- type must be known at this point
   |
help: consider giving `parent` an explicit type, where the type for type parameter `Borrowed` is specified
   |
60 |                 let parent: &Borrowed = parent.borrow();
   |


However specifying &Borrowed gives a completely different error that doesnt really make sense
Couldnt find anything with some google searches or ChatGPT

This happens when you accidentally import std::borrow::Borrow, because then Borrow::borrow shadows RefCell::borrow. I think this happens so often because rust-analyzer likes to put trait methods above inherent methods. So just delete the use std::borrow::Borrow;, or explicitly call RefCell::borrow(parent).
